# Kendo grid MVC5,count of no of records is not showing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

Using kendo grid for displaying the data,instead of the count it showing NAN of NAN items. How can I solve this?

Comment: Provide more details and code segment please.

Comment: Dear @SJaka  i solved it thank u...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using this code in schema Thankss....

```
 schema: {
                data: "Data",
                total: function (response) {
                    return response.Total;
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options, the first you already found it: define a function that computes `total`. The second, in your case, it's much simpler since you only need to say which fields includes the `total`.

Something like:

```
schema: {
    data: "Data",
    total: "Total"
}
```

For more information check the manual [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.total).

[image]